# how do i make the loop reference the next cell?

Tags: excel, vba

The code below will copy and insert text from one sheet to the other the way that I want. However, I don't know how to write a loop to make it work for the rest of the data.  Novice here, so it's probably simple.  It just needs to check the next line on the WS1 sheet and input on the WS2 sheet if the code applies.

I've commented out the loop I wrote that didn't work. I tried startitem = startitem + 1 and startitem = startitem.offset(1)  and couldn't get either to work.

```
Sub transferdata()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ws1     As Worksheet
Dim ws2     As Worksheet
Dim startrow As Range

Dim startpremium As Range
Dim startitem As Range
Dim itemcount As Range


Set ws1 = Sheets("Input")
Set ws2 = Sheets("PakEmail")
Set startrow = ws2.Range("B18")
Set startpremium = ws2.Range("E18")
Set startitem = ws1.Range("D11")
Set itemcount = ws1.Range("D44")
Set copyname = ws1.Range("B11")
Set copypremium = ws1.Range("D11")

'Let X = 0

'Do While X <= itemcount

If startitem <> 0 Then
 copyname.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
 startrow.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
 copypremium.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
 startpremium.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

End If

'X = X + 1

'Loop





Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: Q: Is `itemcount` the range holding the count, or the last item in column D before leaving the loop?

Comment: It is the range holding the count

Answer (score 2):

Couple things to keep in mind... you have about 3 things to keep in mind when performing this:

- 1)  you can use a for or for each loop on the source data to move from row to row (in my example code the variable iterated is *i*)
- 2)  you want to know the last row on the destination sheet (lrs = last row source, lrd = last row destination)
- 3)  keep track of all qualifications as you're moving between source/destination sheets (note where src and dst are utilized)

A general code to work from to keep the above in mind:

```
dim src as worksheet, dst as worksheet, i as long, lrs as long, lrd as long
set src = Sheets("SourcE")
set dst = sheets("Destination")
with src
    lrs = .cells(.rows.count,1).end(xlup).row
    for i = 1 to lrs
        if .cells(i,1).value = "what i want it to be" then
            lrd = dst.cells(dst.rows.count,1).end(xlup).row
            dst.rows(lrd+1).value = .rows(i).value
        end if
    next i
end with
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, haven't been able to get it to work with what I have.

Comment: @M.Isaacs i'm not sure i understand your comment.  you have tried to implement my code and have not had success getting it to work, or were you referring to your efforts in general?

Comment: sorry, was going to add to that, but got distracted trying to fix it. I tried to implement but not sure how to change it to fit what I want.  If the 'last row source' is a fixed row (31), can that be changed? Also, my source destination has text in same column as the blank cells I want to add to, will it correctly find the 'last row'? 
From my previous code i posted, i want 'copyname', 'startrow', 'copypremium', and 'startpremium' to change from their original range to the next row.  i.e.  'copyname' should change from ws1.range("B11') to ws1.range("B12") and run the macro.

Comment: i tried copyname= copyname.offset(1,0) but loop still not working.   If the 'startitem' is blank would that cause a problem? I assumed if it was blank, it wouldn't copy and just move to the next row, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @M.Isaacs `lrs` will find the last row (based on column 1 (A) in my code) every time the code is run; this keeps the source number of rows dynamic, so if you later add more data, you don't have to manually change a value.  This is similar for `lrd`, where the last row is determined dynamically *inside of the loop*, and the destination values will be +1 row from that dynamically determined destination last row.  The use of `Cells(i,column)` in the loop is what allows each cell reference to iterate (i for iterate), so for each of your variables that should iterate can iterate.

Comment: Essentially, you'll want to have less fixed variables and re-do parts of your code to utilize a loop.